# MS SQL Find a Value in entire column and return true if found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

New to SQL trying to find how to do the following :

I have a ProductID# ABC123 (Product) I need to check the "workflow" (Workflow) column and see if the Product ID was ever "extended"
- there are various workflow steps
- Need to check the entire workflow column,  if a ProductID was ever "extended" I need to mark "yes"

Ex :

```
Product ID    Workflow Extended?    
-------------------------------
ABC123        "Yes"
ABC234        "No"
ABC345        "Yes"
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'd select the products from the product table and then check whether there is an extended entry for them in the workflow steps table. This is done with `IN`or `EXISTS`.

```
select
  product_id,
  name,
  case when product_id in
              (select product_id from workflow_steps where workflow = 'extended')
       then 'yes'
       else 'no'
  end as extended
from products
order by product_id;
```

This avoids having to read all rows from the (possibly large) workflow steps table. This table should have an index on the two columns we are interested in to make the lookup happen quickly. The order of the two columns shouldn't matter, I think, but you can play safe and create both indexes. Then in the query's execution plan check which index is used and drop the other one:

```
create index idx1 on workflow_steps(product_id, workflow);
create index idx2 on workflow_steps(workflow, product_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select product_id, max(workflow_extended) workflow_extended_once
from mytable
group by product_id
```

This works because, string-wise, `'Yes'` is greater than `'No'`: so if the given `product_id` is has at least one `'Yes'`, column `workflow_extended_once` will display `'Yes'`. If it has only `'No'`s, `'No'` will be returned.

** Edit **

It looks like you want:

```
select 
    product_id, 
    max(case when workflow = 'extended' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) workflow_extended_once
from mytable
group by product_id
```

Comment: apologies might not have written the question correctly .. "workflow" column has other values ex. new, active, inactive, extend. I need to look though all the values for a product and see if they have "extend" in their workflow and return "Yes" or "No" ..

Answer (score 0):

If want to know if the product has ever extended, it means at least one time it must be extended. And it means simply one row must be marked as extended.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourProductTable WHERE ProductID = 'ABC123' AND Extended = 'Yes') > 0 
--it will return true or false. If true, it means at least one line is marked as Yes.
```

If you need to know if all lines of the product in question are marked Yes to validate the worwkflow column :

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourProductTable WHERE ProductID = 'ABC123' AND Extended <> 'Yes') > 0
```

OR

```
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourProductTable WHERE ProductID = 'ABC123' AND Extended = 'No') > 0 
--Will return true if there is a line marked as No.
```

Comment: If the code is ok for you, you can check as solution. Thanks.